# How can I bypass this message when starting the .exe with cmd?

Tags: cmd, exe

i got following cmd command, i want to start an .exe installer with this, but when i execute it the message after it pops up.

```
START "DSM-Agent setup..." /WAIT /D %PATH% InstallClient.exe
```

The Message:
[image]

I already tried adding domains or something to the registry but nothing worked.
This is in an automation script, so the message is very deal breaking.
I hope someone can help me.

Additional Info:
The script should run on Windows Server OS
The exe is on another server

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it from a network location?

This is the reason for the message.

The network share is not trusted by your computer, so it warns you.

You need to add the network server to your trusted servers:

In Internet Explorer:

Internet Options → Security tab

Local Intranet → Sites

Check Automatically detect intranet network

Advanced → Add this website to the zone:

Enter → `file://path` → OK

** You need to restart explorer.exe for the changes to take effect

Comment: Yep i already did what you mentioned, but it still didnt work.

Comment: Before 10 seconds i changed following:
I deactivated the  Internet Explorer Enhanced Security and now everything works